# Combine a base URL and append an ID to the end by each element in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Forgive me, I have not used JavaScript in 10 years and I want to include any details to help me better understand.

I want to fetch data from an external API using Google Scripts into Google Sheets. Instead of fetching all data, I want to only fetch the data that I have defined in an array.

I'm attempting to join a base URL and add an ID for the data I want specifically.

I have the base URL, and a undefined end of the URL:

```
const urlBase = 'https://website/item?q';
var urlEnd = '';
```

I've tried to use `join(\'=\')` for each element of an array.

The Array looks something like this: (I wanted to output it in different sections when I'm fetching the data)

```
const itemData0 = ['1da94960-5a14-4cb0-bc25-23a07ecbc915','7ecda500-745e-4275-8b4e-b883b0a28139']
const itemData1 = ['60769d56-6fe0-464f-9d6c-d2a1b6ca6e18','a53b9b6e-3671-43fe-9429-08224083bb11']
const priceData0 = ['0080307d-3596-440c-be38-bdded3cbf4cf','5ac84494-465a-424a-b36e-fe22869ba5ec']
...
```

The URL should end up being: `https://website/item?q=1da94960-5a14-4cb0-bc25-23a07ecbc915`

Which should give me,

```
Header: Items 0
Row0: Data1, Data1a (Each Url ID)
...

Header: Items 1
Row0: Data1, Data1a
...
```

The API endpoint: (Adding, the `let i=o; i<array.length; i++` for each array to replace url)
And collecting Data:

```
function getItemData() {
  let urlData = [];
  for (let i=0; i<urlEnd.length; i++) { 
  urlData[i] = [];
  urlData[i][0] = urlEnd[i].itemData0;
  urlData[i][1] = urlEnd[i].itemData1;
  urlData[i][2] = urlEnd[i].priceData0;
  urlEnd.forEach("join function")
  }

  let data = fetchJSON('https://website/item?q=' + urlData);
  let range = ssPrivateData.getRange(`A${1 + HEADER_ROWS_COUNT}:E${1 + HEADER_ROWS_COUNT + data.length - 1}`);

  let sheetData = [];
  for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    sheetData[i] = [];
    sheetData[i][0] = data[i].id;
    sheetData[i][1] = data[i].name;
    sheetData[i][2] = data[i].price;
    sheetData[i][3] = data[i].date;
    sheetData[i][4] = data[i].lastSale;
  }

  range.setValues(sheetData);

  setLastUpdateDate();
}

function fetchJSON(url) {
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { 'x-api-key': API_KEY }});
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    return data;
  }
  catch(err) {
    status = err.message;
  }
  return status;
}
```

I cannot get the URLs to combine for each of the arrays. I've tried running this script offline to pull random data to test formatting, but I cannot even get the data to input.

> **UPDATE**

What I did was take all the data instead of the specific ID's. and then filtered the the data that wasn't equal to the array defined. Look at one of the answers, I've explained what I did differently.

Sorry the question wasn't easily understood. hopefully my answer below clarifies what I was trying to do. I still don't know how to append a URL and add ID to it. I feel filtering is better as I dont have to query each time for each ID there is. I just do it once, and ignore the id's I don't want.

Comment: Could you show the value of `urlEnd`?

Comment: @TheMaster the url end is the array i stated before the API endpoint

Comment: Where? You have 3 arrays named three different things.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this line `urlEnd.forEach("join function")`. Is that your actual question? Also you are not using `urlEnd`. It doesn't seem to be even initialized. 
And in this line `  let data = fetchJSON('https://website/item?q=' + urlData);
` you are concatenating a `string` and an `array`, did you mean `urlEnd` in this case? Could you maybe do your quesiton more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I filtered the total results instead of appending each ID to a url.

```
var filtered_items = { 
 item_data1 : [array 1],
 item_data2 : [array 2]
};

let sheetData = [ ['header 1', 'header 2']];

var row_data = [];

for(var set_key in filtered_items) { 
row_data = [ set_key, '', '','', '','',];

sheetData.push(row_data);

for (var k in filtered_items[set_key][k] {

    for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

        if (data[i].id == filtered_items[set_key][k]) {

            row_data = [
              set_key,
                  sheetData[i].id;
                  sheetData[i].name;
                  sheetData[i].price;
                  sheetData[i].date;
                  sheetData[i].lastSale;
                 ];

                 sheetData.push(row_data);

                break;

              }
         }
     }
     row_data = ['','','', '','',];

sheetData.push(row_data);

}

....
```